# Cannot unlock Metamask

Tags: metamask

I cannot unlock my Metamask.  When trying to unlock, I get this message "network request failed.  What should I do?  I tried the other suggestion that I found online like switching to another network but have not had success.

Comment: Add more information to your question with some snippets of code you are trying and the error.

Comment: I have nothing else to add.  I have used metamask in the past and never had any problems.  I  simply want to know what can be done to unlock the software.  I restored it last week and set up the new password I am using.